# how to get HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext() in startup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, startup

I very read for this problem but i can not  fixed this so i think create a new question in this site.

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
```

i want get GetOwinContext values with above code . above code there are in my startup.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(OwinTest.Startup))]

public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        var c = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
    }
}
```

and i get this error

//No owin.Environment item was found in the context

but `var c = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();` work for me in HomeController fine.!

I just get GetOwinContext in my startup.cs class.

thankfull

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that.  The OWIN context does not exist without a request, and the Startup class only runs once for the application, not for each request.  Your Startup class should initialize your middleware and your application and the middleware and the application should access the OWIN context when needed.

Comment: @MichaleDotKnow, do you have any idea about how to create an owin context without an HTTP context? I need to some start up that involves creating a user but, in order to do that, I'm stuch without the owinContext.Authentication (instance of IAuthenticationManager).

Comment: Or perhaps you have an idea about how to create an instance of authentication manager without the owin context.

Comment: @FabioMilheiro, that's probably a little broad for a comment to really answer.  You should probably create a new question.  But gut feel is that since IAuthenticationManager is in the OWIN namespace, that you probably need the OWINContext.  But that's just a guess without seeing more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I managed to get going without the `OwinContext.Authentication` as I don't really need authentication - just the creation of some user records. I won't create the question now but still appreciate your time. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, what you are asking isn't possible. However, depending on your requirements, the following is possible and gives you access within the context of creating object instances. This is something I needed in order to check for whether an instance was already added else where (I have multiple startup classes in different projects).

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
     ConfigureAuth(app);

     // Ensure we have our "main" access setup
     app.CreatePerOwinContext<DataAccessor>(
            (options, owinContext) => 
            {
                // Check that an instance hasn't already been added to
                // the OwinContext in another plugin
                return owinContext.Get<DataAccessor>() ?? DataAccessor.CreateInstance(options, owinContext);
            }
        );
}
```

Within the `CreatePerOwinContext` we have access to the `OwinContext`, so we can access it at the point of creating a new type. This might not help everyone as it's a little more specific to a person's needs, but is useful to know.